# How to load local_repository dependencies on external dependency in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

Project `MAIN` has multiple local_repository rules: `A, B, C`. They are added into a common macro and loaded by MAIN WORKSPACE file:

```
def load_dependencies():
  native.local_repository(name="A"...) # many of those
  ...
```

Now, I want to create new project `NEW` which depends on `MAIN`. MAIN is loaded by `git_repository` repository_rule.

How to properly load these local repositories?

I can't just hardcode absolute path to `MAIN` root dir since it is downloaded by git.

Answer (score 0):

If MAIN is imported into NEW using a git_repository rule like this:

```py
git_repository(
    name = "MAIN",
    <other stuff>
)
```

then you can load that macro into NEW's workspace and use it like this:

```py
load("@MAIN//path/to:the_file.bzl", "load_dependencies")

load_dependencies()
```

`git_repository` is used instead of `local_repository`. They both create a Bazel [repository](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/build-ref.html#repositories) which you can reference with labels. Once you have the `git_repository`, you don't need a path like you would with `local_repository` because it's already a repository.